# cassandra how I can get data with 2 tables?

Tags: cassandra

In cassandra joins are not supported. So I want to show 20 Videos with comments.

I saw this example from a data modelling:

```
CREATE TABLE videos (
   id number(12),
   userid number(12) NOT NULL,
   name nvarchar2(255),
   description nvarchar2(500),
   location nvarchar2(255),
   location_type int,
   added_date timestamp,
   CONSTRAINT users_userid_fk FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE comments (
   id number(12),
   userId number(12),
   videoId number(12),
   comment_text nvarchar2(500),
   comment_time timestamp(6),
   PRIMARY KEY (id),
   CONSTRAINT user_comment_fk FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   CONSTRAINT video_comment_fk FOREIGN KEY (videoId) REFERENCES videos (Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

So how can I get now all videos with comments ? Because joins are not supported.

Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You are right that Cassandra does not support joins. And reason for that joins may become slow for big web scale data and Cassandra was designed to solve that particular problem.

Now coming back to your problem, to solve this in Cassandra it it recommended to create a table (call it a join table) which can answer your query. So if you want to see list of videos with comments, you can group videos and comments in a single partition using user_id as partition key. The table can look like this

```
CREATE TABLE KEYSPACE.videos_comments_by_user_id (\
user_id int,\
video_id int,\
comments list\<text>,
PRIMARY KEY((user_id), video_id);
```

Comment: I do not understand. How can I group data ? I mean I have the videoID  but no information about the name description etc

Comment: Its just an example to show how join problems are solved in Cassandra. The main thing here is that you will have to create a table which can get you all the data which you require. The other option (non Cassandra solution) is fetching results from two different tables and joining at client side. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

While designing a table in Cassandra one should always keep one thing in mode, What query does this table shall serve? Do not think about joining the two tables, that will never work with Cassandra. Instead design to serve a query.

Below is the table design which will serve your query-

```
Table   
comments_by_user_videos
```

Columns

```
 Userid
 Videoid
 CommentId
 CommentTimeStam
 Videoname static
 VideoDescription static
 Location static
 Location type static
 Comment_text

 Constraints-
  Primary Key ((userid,videoid), CommentId).
```

The static columns are shared for a row kye. In this design  , user id and video id define one row so for a user id and video id the value of static columns remains same. Static column can used to represent one to many relationship.

Query- to get all the comments for a video of a user.

```
   Select * from comments_by_user_videos where userid=? and videoid=?
```

Edit:

If you want to display few number of vides, you should design another table.

```
Table: user_videos

userid
timestamp
videoid
videoname
videoLocation
locationtype


Primary key (userid, videoid, timestamp) ordered by timestamp DESC

Query:
select * from users_by_id_name where userid=? limit 10;
```

The query should return latest 10 videos by user.
Insert data in to both tables, never hesitate to duplicate data.

Comment: Hey thanks! But I have one question. If you logged in my app you see directly videos with comments without a video id. I will show 10 videos

Comment: @localdata01 In this case you should have two tables